# Google Map APIを用いたアプリのソースコードについて

Tags: javascript, google-maps

下記リンクのアプリに関して質問させていただきます。
http://notlion.github.com/streetview-stereographic

ページを読み込むと、下記のようにパラメータが渡されます。

## o=0,0,0,1&z=1.509&mz=17&p=-23.61622,-46.59109

この#o=0,0,0,1の値がstreet viewの画面の何の操作に対応するものなのかを教えて頂けませんでしょうか。
下記ソースのQuat(x, y, z, w)に対応することまでは分かったのですが、
例えば、現在表示されているパノラマ画像を平面的に時計回りに90度回転させる、
といった操作はどのように実現できるかを知りたいです。
https://github.com/notlion/embr/blob/54afc5dc5caff71d4b4e066ff0da431327e36501/src/core/Quat.js

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map APIの仕様は見ていませんが、Quatはクォータニオン(四元数)です。実数の4つ組み`(x, y, z, w)`で3次元空間での回転を表します。

単位ベクトル V = (Vx, Vy, Vz) 回りにθラジアン回転させる操作はクォータニオン `(Vx*sin(θ/2), Vy*sin(θ/2), Vz*sin(θ/2), cos(θ/2))` に対応します。`(0,0,0,1)`はθ=0の場合ですね。

平面的に90度、はVを鉛直なベクタにしてθ=π/2とすればできます。該当アプリだとZ軸が垂直方向みたいなので、`(0,0,.707,.707)`くらいでいけませんかね。